# OpenStack soft reboot instance vs. sudo reboot

Tags: openstack

Is there any difference between performing an OpenStack soft reboot instance through the web interface Horizon and SSH into the instance and perform `sudo reboot`?

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Is-there-any-difference-between-performing-an-OpenStack-soft-reboot-instance-through-the-web-interface-SSH-into-the-instance-perform-sudo-reboot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [OpenStack Dashboard Server Reboot](https://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/compute/server_concepts.html#server-actions)

> Use this function to perform either a soft or hard reboot of a server. With a soft reboot, the operating system is signaled to restart, which allows for a graceful shutdown of all processes. A hard reboot is the equivalent of power cycling the server. The virtualization platform should ensure that the reboot action has completed successfully even in cases in which the underlying domain/VM is paused or halted/stopped.

### [Nova Server Reboot](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/server.html#server-reboot)

- OpenStack soft reboot:

  ```
  $ nova reboot INSTANCE
  ```
- OpenStack hard reboot:

  ```
  $ nova reboot --hard INSTANCE
  ```

### Server Reboot

If you perform `sudo reboot` OpenStack will not know whether the reboot was intentional...